# @try-@finally for guaranteed elimination of memory leaks when dealing with objects not tracked by ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, memory, memory-management

Suppose we manually allocating memory with `malloc()/calloc()` or allocating some objects that aren't tracked by ARC (like `CGContextRef`). Then, we're doing some stuff. And eventually, we need to free that memory.

Example:

```
void *buf = NULL;     // malloc() allocated object example
CGContextRef context; // Non-manageable by ARC object example

@try {
    buf = malloc(bufSize);
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate(buf, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);

    // Some exception-prone stuff is going here
}
@catch (NSException *e) {
    // ...
}
@finally {
    CGContextRelease(context);
    free(buf);
}
```

Is putting a memory allocation/de-allocation in a @try-@finally the best/proper/recommended approach to guarantee that it would be freed in case if exception is thrown in the "do stuff" section?

If not, could you suggest a better technique and explain why it's preferable?

Comment: I'd fix the problems causing the exceptions.

Comment: Placing memory releasing code in `@finally` block is OK, but you need to check if your variables like `context` and `buf` are not `NULL` to avoid freeing NULL pointer.

Comment: @maddy: Yes, we can do it to a certain extent. But what if in the stuff section you're doing, for instance, some kind of disk/network I/O which potentially could cause a number of different exceptions?

Comment: @AndrewTomenko: I'm not sure about the `CGContextRelease(context);` call with uninitialized structures in my example, but calling `free(NULL);` is a completely safe no-op operation ([http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/]).

Comment: `CGContextRelease` is safe to call on `NULL`. It is one of numerous `...Release` variants that work around the fact that `CFRelease(NULL)` is (bizarrely) illegal.

Comment: Note that disk/network I/O in cocoa should not generate exceptions. There are some rare exceptions (hah!) to that, but the answer is to not call those methods. (There are a small handful that are very hard to avoid (in `NSConnection` for instance), and are frankly a problem w/ Cocoa, and you kind of just pray they don't happen to you.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is putting a memory allocation/de-allocation in a @try-@finally the best/proper/recommended approach to guarantee that it would be freed in case if exception is thrown in the "do stuff" section?

No.

An ObjC exception should always be expected to lead to a crash in the near future. Fully recovering from a `@try` is bad ObjC; eventually you should always re-throw the exception to allow the program to crash. Your question is actually a bit backwards, worrying about non-ARC-managed objects. Unless you're compiling as ObjC++, ARC intentionally leaks like a sieve after an ObjC exception.

The correct approach is to eliminate the exceptions. There should be no such thing as "Some exception-prone stuff is going here" in ObjC. ObjC is not (and has never been intended to be) an exception-safe language. When compiled as ObjC++ there is extra work done (and extra runtime overhead) to try to make it more exception-safe because C++ exceptions are common, but this shouldn't be taken as a reason to use `@try`.

[Clang's explanation of ARC with exceptions](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#exceptions) is an excellent primer on the topic. Most enlightening is this section (emphasis added):

> **The standard Cocoa convention is that exceptions signal programmer error and are not intended to be recovered from.** Making code exceptions-safe by default would impose severe runtime and code size penalties on code that typically does not actually care about exceptions safety. Therefore, ARC-generated code leaks by default on exceptions, which is just fine if the process is going to be immediately terminated anyway. Programs which do care about recovering from exceptions should enable the option.

Also of use is [Exception Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Articles/ExceptionsAndCocoaFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009045-SW1):

> The Cocoa frameworks are generally not exception-safe. The general pattern is that exceptions are reserved for programmer error only, and the program catching such an exception should quit soon afterwards.

The only reason to use `@catch` is because you'd like to create some kind of diagnostics to help you understand the crash (and doing this correctly is a very advanced topic not for the faint of heart or novice). It is never intended to rescue you from a programming error.

Note that ObjC's `@try` is completely unrelated to Swift's `try`. Swift's `try` is just a fancy/magical `return` (it's not even an "exception" in the way that's commonly meant in other languages).

Comment: This also means that in ObjC, you should NEVER throw exceptions by yourself when an issue is unrecoverable at the current layer in the hope that some upper layer take care of it and would be able to recover. You should return some error code status instead. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. You should only throw an exception when you consider the issue a programming error and entirely unrecoverable. In practice, this is pretty much never done with `@throw` except in low-level library code. In some rare occasions it is done by constructing an `NSException` (often with one of the well-known names) and calling `-raise`, but even that is very uncommon in practice. By far the most common way to raise exceptions is with `NSAssert` or `NSParameterAssert` (or their `...C...` variants). But you should always raise exceptions expecting that the program will soon crash.